# What is the best ffmpeg command keeping the best quality to convert a m3u8 file into a mp4 file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

Ok so I downloaded a *.m3u8* file on the Internet. I saw that this file extension corresponds to a HTTP Live Streaming protocol also called HLS. This protocol consists of an index file (the *m3u8* file) that is a text file containing several URL redirecting to *.ts* files. Those *.ts* files are video files where each one are a little part of the whole video. Then I searched and found on Wikipedia and on the Apple website that this protocol embeds the MPEG-4 (H.264) video format.

If I'm not mistaken *.mp4* is the file extension of the MPEG-4 (H.264) video format. So a *mp4* file is always a MPEG-4 (H.264) video. I use **ffmpeg** to convert this *.m3u8* file into a "normal" video file. Currently I use this command :

`ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tcp,tls" -i input.m3u8 output.mp4`

Although even if the video quality is almost perfect it's a little below the quality of the original *m3u8* file. I know I'm really pernickety but is there a better command to keep the original quality ? Or does the **ffmpeg** convertion command involve inevitably a quality loss ?

Comment: I have a little bonus question. What are the reason a website would prefer to use the HLS protocol to display a video on their website instead of just putting a mp4 file directly reachable on the server ?

Comment: The typical use case of HLS is rendering multiple qualities at different bitrates and resolution ('renditions' or 'variants'). Because it is served as a sequence of tiny segments, when the client's bandwidth capacity changes, players can seamlessly switch to more suitable renditions.

Answer (score 4):

No need to re-encode the streams, use

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tcp,tls" -i input.m3u8 -c copy output.mp4
```

`-c` is short for `-codec`; if not set, ffmpeg will re-encode the streams.

MP4 is a file format standardized by the ISO (14496 Part 12 & 14). H.264 is a video codec standard, specified in ISO 14496 Part 10. An MP4 can contain video streams with codec other than H.264.